# Проблема с кодировкой при отсылке письма

Tags: php, кодировка

Добрый день!

```
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0 Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8';
$subject = 'Я люблю людей!';
$mailtxt = 'Грёбанный кибастут!';
mb_language("uni");
mb_send_mail("peoples@yandex.ru", $subject, $mailtxt, $headers);
```

Почему в письме не отображается текст?
Проблема в коде, или в .htaccess? Вот кстати, я приведу его содержимое:

```
RemoveHandler .html .htm
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .htm .html
php_value mbstring.func_overload 1
php_value mbstring.internal_encoding UTF-8
php_value mbstring.http_output UTF-8
php_value mbstring.http_input UTF-8
```

Comment: А где заголовки и тело письма?

Comment: Тело письма содержится в $mailtxt, заголовок в $headers)

Comment: Вы не поняли - я хочу посмотреть на результат выполнения кода :-) в виде "raw" текста письма.
Тогда и скажу в чем трабл. А так - мне сложно сказать. Я не настолько мегаэксперт по php.

Comment: Результат таков: мне приходит письмо, но русские символы исчезли, остались лишь знаки препинания + английский текст. Короче говоря, если не знаешь flash-решения, то не парьтесь, gecube:(
Я в принципе могу отсылать письмо в формате iso-8859-1, но в GMail_е в списке писем выводится абракадабра, там где после subject'a идёт пару слов preview'a письма, вот так:
-- 18:19 [OwnerNavigator from Вася Пупкин]сÔ.È.Î ñîèñêàòåëÿ Âàÿñ 
--
Это не эстетично, очень плохо, хотя в тексте письма всё ок.
Советуют использовать ТОЛЬКО utf-8, но как видишь у меня вообще русский текст обрезается.

Comment: А кодировка скрипта наверняка CP-1251 (ANSI)?

Answer (score 1):

Саму страницу со скриптом перекодируйте в UTF-8, удачи и новых побед ;)